# Alternative to data frame in R

Tags: r

What's the right type of object to encapsulate objects of different type in R? Data frames don't seem to be the right type of object for this? Data frames have a number of entries each having the same sub-fields.

What I need is a single object, with different sub-objects some of which might be arrays.

Example:

```
score<-0.95
confidence_in_score<-0.5
confidence_interval<-c(0,1)
token<-"foobar"
object_to_return<-data.frame(score,confidence_in_score,confidence_interval,token)


  score confidence_in_score confidence_interval token
1  0.05                 0.5                   0   ggg
2  0.05                 0.5                   1   ggg
```

What I really want is a container where one element will be an array confidence_interval with just two elements.

Motivation: To pass back to the calling program a single object instead of several individual sub-objects.

Comment: Try a `list` then. You can quickly pick all of these from the global environment using `l <- mget(ls())`, for instance.

Comment: See section 6.1 of [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf). Please read the whole document.

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg. That works well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
# next 4 lines are from question 
score<-0.95
confidence_in_score<-0.5
confidence_interval<-c(0,1)
token<-"foobar"

list(score = score, 
     confidence_in_score = confidence_in_score, 
     confidence_interval = confidence_interval, 
     token = token)
```

As an example of returning a list from R itself look at the last line of source code of `eigen`.  It returns a list with two components named `values` and `vectors`. (Just type `eigen` on a line by itself in R to see its source.)

Try `?list` from within R for more info and examples.

These links may also be helpful:

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Lists-and-data-frames

http://www.homogenisation.org/admin/docs/Lists&DataFrames.pdf

Answer (score 4):

The object you look for is a `list`. The sub-elements of a list can contain any kind of R object. For example:

```
str(list(mtcars, summary(mtcars), c('bla', 'spam', 'ham'), array(runif(1000))))
List of 4
 $ :'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
  ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
  ..$ cyl : num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
  ..$ disp: num [1:32] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
  ..$ hp  : num [1:32] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
  ..$ drat: num [1:32] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
  ..$ wt  : num [1:32] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
  ..$ qsec: num [1:32] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
  ..$ vs  : num [1:32] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ am  : num [1:32] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ gear: num [1:32] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
  ..$ carb: num [1:32] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
 $ : 'table' chr [1:6, 1:11] "Min.   :10.40  " "1st Qu.:15.43  " "Median :19.20  " "Mean   :20.09  " ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "" "" "" "" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:11] "     mpg" "     cyl" "     disp" "      hp" ...
 $ : chr [1:3] "bla" "spam" "ham"
 $ : num [1:1000(1d)] 0.5061 0.0806 0.4081 0.5038 0.8896 ...
```

The [following tutorial](http://stcorp.nl/R_course/tutorial_interacting_with_data_structures.html) I wrote could be of benefit to you.

Answer (score -3):

I would NOT recommend a list. Every set of data can be represented in a relational database, which is much easier to work with. In your case, you have two options:

```
data = data.frame(score = 0.95,
                  confidence_in_score = 0.5,
                  confidence_interval_lower_limit = 0,
                  confidence_interval_upper_limit = 1,
                  token = "foobar")
```

Or

```
interval = data.frame(score = 0.95,
                      confidence_in_score = 0.5,
                      token = "foobar")

limit = data.frame(token = c("foobar", "foobar"),
                   type = c("lower_limit", "upper_limit"),
                   value= c(0, 1) )
```

You can use dplyr and tidyr to easily manipulate this data. For example,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  select(token, 
         confidence_interval_lower_limit,
         confidence_interval_upper_limit) %>%
  gather(type, value, -token)
```

or

```
interval %>%
  spread(type, value) %>%
  full_join(limit)
```

Two rules of relational data are:

Never repeat information anywhere except for ID columns

No cell should contain more than one piece of information

Comment: Did you even see a `dput` of a data.frame ? Try `dput(limit)` , data.frames are just enhanced lists

Comment: Yes, but they have extra features. Like every sublist/vector is required to be exactly the same length. Dataframes have both rowwise and columnwise relationships.

Comment: May you explain what you mean by rowwise relationships ?

Comment: That all data in a row is related to each other. Lists don't have an equivalent of a row.

Comment: Aww, ok, but you did read the question and see the op wished one column containing a _vector_ of values right ? Which you can't do with a df which will make multiples rows for this (as you stated in your answer), that's why I don't see how this could answer the question anyway.

Comment: And a df row if a list index, each objects at this index are related in the same way, just that you may have compound objects within. I'm not sure if it's really impossible with a data.frame, but I see no obvious way to achieve it top of my head.